# Buttons not showing when dynamically adding to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to add number of buttons depending upon counter. I have button which increments the counter. The problem is it shows buttons in odd click. It does not show up in even clicks. For example when i click first, it shows one button. I click again, no button shows up. On third time, It shows three buttons and so on. Can anyone please tell me what can be the issue. I am posting increment code and buttons displaying code.

```
<code>
    animalsEasyLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.animalsEasyLayout);
    forward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("mustang", "Increment");
                    increment();
                    showDigitImages();
                }
            });


            backward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("mustang", "Decrement");
                    decrement();
                    showDigitImages();
                }
            });
        }

        private void increment()
        {
            counter++;
            digitView.setText("" + counter);

            if(counter >= 10)
            {
                forward.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                forward.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        private void showDigitImages()
        {
            Log.i("mustang", "Show images for counter: " + counter);
            animalsEasyLayout.removeAllViews();


            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


            for(int count = 0; count < counter; count++)
            {

                final Button b = new Button(this);
                b.setId(count + 1);
                b.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                b.setText("Child: " + (++count));

                animalsEasyLayout.addView(b);
            }
        }

        private void decrement()
        {
            counter--;
            digitView.setText("" + counter);

            if(counter <= 0)
            {
                backward.setEnabled(false); 
            }
            else
            {
                backward.setEnabled(true);
            }

        }

</code>
```

Comment: Just for curiousity, why are you removing and re-adding all views. Why not add one view on the click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing the `count` twice - once in the `for` statement and once inside the loop while you call `setText`.

```
        for(int count = 0; count < counter; count++)
        {

            final Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setId(count + 1);
            b.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            b.setText("Child: " + (++count));

            animalsEasyLayout.addView(b);
        }
```

use

```
 b.setText("Child: "+ (count + 1));
```